# Stylus цикл for: можно ли сочетать диапазон и отдельные значения

Tags: циклы, stylus

Можно ли в Stylus задать для цикла for вместе и диапазон значений, и отдельные значения?

```
for item in range(2, 7) 14 33
    li:nth-child({item}) label
        color red
```

или

```
for item in 2..7 14 33
    li:nth-child({item}) label
        color red
```

Данный код не работает. Работает, только ИЛИ диапазон, или отдельные значения.

Comment: Наверно нельзя, что мешает прописать `for item in 2 3 4 5 6 7 14 33`?

Comment: @greybutton
много цифр писать, выглядит плохо. Лучше уж на CSS: `:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+10):not(:nth-child(6)):`, например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ получен на https://stackoverflow.com/a/42610706/873481

Перевожу и цитирую код:

> К сожалению, в Stylus нет ничего подобного concat из стандартной
>   библиотеки, только push, но можно легко написать так:
>
> ```
> concat()
>   ret = ()
>   for item in arguments
>     push(ret, item)
>   ret
>
> body
>   for i in concat(range(0, 5), 10, 55)
>     test: i
> ```